# Assign a formula at runtime for accessing elements of List

Tags: c#, for-loop, lambda, delegates, action

The scenario is that I have say two different types of cases - case 1 and case 2. For case 1 and case 2 each I have a certain startIndex, endIndex and a formula for accessing the elements of a List.

Now for assigning values startIndex and endIndex I am preferring a normal switch case, however I am at loss for the formula for accessing elements. For **case 1** it is say something like **List[ a+i ]** and for **case 2** it is say **List[a + (i-b)]**. 
    One way can be to have a for loop like this

```
for(int i=0;;i++)
{ 
     if(case is 1)
        then f=a+i 
     else if(case 2)
        then f=a+(i-b) 
}
```

I thought of using delegates. however, as per my knowledge they need to be made global. Actions do not return value. Func can be used but one expression/formula takes only one element (int) and the other takes 3. I need something in lines to this like that anonymous function can be assigned any of above mentioned formulae at runtime from the switch case (as the cases might and will increase in future).

Thank you.

Comment: what lists are you using? which ranges of your list are you using? what is case?

Comment: Would a `Func<int, int, int, int>` work? You can also create a custom delegate type with named parameters.

Comment: Oops my bad I forgot to inform that I am doing this in C#. Cases are simple. the expression of switch is an Enum value. I am just assigning values to few variables inside the cases, which I then use inside the for loop. And lists are lists of objects and the list is System.Collection.Generic. What really the problem is to have a way by which I can have different formulae in each of those cases which has int i from the for loop (which comes after the switch case) as one of the variable, and than use the selected formula to access the corresponding element from the list

Comment: @usr I tried Func<int,int,int,int> however it might not work as one formula has 2 ints and other has 3. And also the var used in for loop's condition is also to be used in those formulae. one thing what I can do is to make the variable local to the function and use while instead of for. that will solve half of my problem. However, how can I use Func or lambda to take int inputs ( between 2 ints ,3 ints and 4 ints) and return a single int?

Comment: @sam Func<int[], int>?

Comment: @usr than I will have to access the int[] elements with hard coded values right? something like - int[0] + (int[1] - int[2]). Which means I will have to be cautious while putting elements in the array, right?

Comment: @Samarth yes but it's the only choice since you say that you can't use a fixed number of arguments. Frankly, your scenario is not clear to me. Can you post more complete code.

Comment: @usr I have achieved what I wanted (Have posted a code snippet of solution as an answer). I used what you suggested of using int[] in func. However, it would really be awesome if we can get to use params with delegates, Func and Actions.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of using delegates. however, as per my knowledge they need
>   to be made global.

This is not true (actually, there are no truly global variables in C#, since each and every variable needs to be encapsulated inside an object). A public delegate *type* is indeed visible to all code after referencing the assembly containing this type's code, but a *variable* of such type can be private.

What I recommend in your situation is to have some sort of mapping from case numbers to delegates. A good idea is to use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` if you have at most one delegate per case. This dictionary can be stored as a private variable inside the class where your method resides.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<int, Delegate> _delegateMapping = new Dictionary<int, Delegate>;
}
```

There are a couple of ways you can add elements do the dictionary in the constructor: passing the already populated dictionary, passing an array of delegates, creating these delegates in the constructor itself. Either way, you'll end up with a dictionary of `Delegate` types, so you'll need to use a cast to be able to use them in your code properly.

```
 for (int i = 1; i < _delegateMapping.Count; i++)
 {
     switch (i)
     {
         case 1:
             var f = (Action<int>)_delegateMapping[1];
             f(i);
             break;
         case 2:
             var f = (Action<int, int>)_delegateMapping[2];
             f(i, a);
             break;
     }
 }
```

Of course I'm greatly improvising here.

It is important to note that if the type of delegate changes inside the dictionary, you will have to modify the cast accordingly inside the `switch` statement. Otherwise, if no implicit cast exists, you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: that's good solution and one of the best. However, I have my switch case before and outside the for loop. And inside that switch case I have to assign a formula (which also uses i) which will than be executed in the for loop. Also on more thing. Can actions have return type? Than too I will try your said idea.

Comment: @Samarth This doesn't change the fact that you can use a dictionary here. My code showing the use of the dictionary was just a made-up example, I never intended to write it as a concrete solution to your problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks I tried a solution using a dictionary storing the funcs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thank you so very much for your feedbacks. I finally found the solution with Func. This is what my code looks like. I had to manipulate the Func usage a little. I made almost all the vars which I have to use in the Func as global/local to the function where I write these Funcs. My apologies, if I was not able to explain my problem properly.

```
        int i = -1;
        Func<int,int> formula = null;

        switch(f)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                formula = new Func<int,int>(index => { return i; });
            }
            break;

            case 2:
            {
                formula = new Func<int, int>( index => { return s- (i * c); } );//here s and c are global variables.
            }
            break;
        }
        i = startIndex;

        while(i < endIndex)
        {
            var Obj= List[formula.Invoke(i)];
            //my code goes here
            i++;
        }
```

Let me know if my solution is correct w.r.t performance, logic, C# programming, etc.. :)

EDITED::
@usr and @Kapol I tried the way you suggested and tried to improvise the code like this.

```
    private Dictionary<int, Func<int[], int>> indexFormulae;

    private void assignDelegates()
    {
        indexFormulae = new Dictionary<int, Func<int[], int>>();
        indexFormulae.Add(0, getFormula_1);
        indexFormulae.Add(1, getFormula_2);
    } 
    private void someFunction(int sp)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Func<int[], int> formula = null;
        indexFormulae.TryGetValue(formation,out formula);

        i = startIndex;
        while (i < endIndex)
        {
            int[] intValues = new int[] {i,sp,globalVar };
            var Obj = List[formula.Invoke(intValues)];
            //My code here
            i++;
        }
    }

    private int getFormula_1(params int[] intValues)
    {
        return intValues[0];
    }

    private int getIndex_Vertical(params int[] intValues)
    {
        return intValues[1] - (intValues[0] * intValues[2]); 
    }
```

So, that with this now I can use these two getFormula methods anywhere in this class rather than keeping them anonymous. and also I think I will stick to params because I might have N number of int params in future for other functions.